# Rotate PNG by ImageMagick

Tags: rotation, imagemagick, transparent

I want to rotate PNG file by convert command.
like this.

```
convert -background 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)' -rotate 45 1.png r1.png
```

But result PNG file is wrong like following.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqzGWe_mT6dwdEIwa04xRldwVGtOX1VGbVJhRnZwX0E

The gray space is correct.

I don't know why black space exists.

What am I wrong?

thank you.

---

convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.5.4-7 2012-05-07 Q16 OpenMP http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2009 ImageMagick Studio LLC

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The image to modify comes straight after convert.

Try:

```
convert 1.png -background "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)" -rotate 45 r1.png
```

Comment: I'm using version "ImageMagick 6.5.4-7 2012-05-07". I installed by yum. OS is CentOS 6.2

Comment: I can rotate it correctry!! I installed latest version ImageMagick(6.8.0-7) from source. Thank you ;)

Comment: There has been a few changes in the png functions in Imagemagick over the last year. Glad its now sorted.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
$ convert 1.png -distort SRT -ANGLE_IN_DEGREES -gravity center r1.png
```

Comment: this rotates just the content of the images, not the image itself